# Atomic way to create firebase auth account and firestore entry

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building this flutter app in which a user can sign Up using firebase auth. When this happens, I have a firebase cloud function that listen to the `onCreate` authentication event and create an entry for that user with additional infos in firestore.

In my UI, at the moment the user is authenticated on the firebase auth system (i listen to the `onAuthStateChanged`), I try to init my app using his info stored in firestore.

The thing is, there is a delay between the time the user is authenticated on the firebase auth system and the time the entry is created on firestore which break my UI.

Is there an atomic way to create a user account and a entry for him in firestore that would solve that problem?

Comment: why do it via a cloud trigger?  there's always going to be a lag on that.  you could create the firebase user then write to firestore from the client in the callback (or even do that in reverse order).

Comment: @blaneyneil Cause in my mind, this kind of business logic shouldn't reside on the client. Plus the problem stay the same if I do it from the client, there will still be a delay

Comment: I've created a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1277) for tackling this problem.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but I thought I would add a suggestion as I'm facing a similar issue/problem and it could be good to talk this through. A proposed option for tackling this could be to use a Firebase Function to create the user in both Firebase Auth and in Firestore, and then respond with a success statement to the client, at which point the client uses the user's details again to authenticate. I can't see any major issues with this approach other than a slightly longer delay in account creation. It appears Functions can access Auth through admin.